# How to find matching values in two arrays?

Tags: c

I need to get the user to input 6 numbers and I store those in an array called winningNum[]. Then I have to read in a file that has a bunch of users firstName lastName and the numbers they have guessed. I need to compare these two arrays and only print out the first and last name of the users from the file that got a minimum of three numbers matched.

This is the struct of for the input file users

```
typedef struct
{
    char firstName [20];
    char lastName [20];
    int numbers[6];
}KBLottoPlayer;
```

Getting the winning numbers from the user

```
int getNum()
{
    int winningNum[6];
        int i;

    printf("Please enter the six nunbers between 1-53:\n");
        scanf("%d %d %d %d %d %d", &winningNum[0], &winningNum[1], 
&winningNum[2] ,&winningNum[3], &winningNum[4], &winningNum[5] );
}
```

This is where I am reading in the file and putting it into the struct array

```
KBLottoPlayer* readArray()
{
    int i,size;
    FILE *in = fopen("KnightsBall.in","r");
        fscanf(in,"%d",&size);

KBLottoPlayer* temp;
temp =(KBLottoPlayer*)malloc(sizeof(KBLottoPlayer)*size);

    if((in = fopen("KnightsBall.in", "r")) != NULL )
  {
        char buffer[100];
        fgets(buffer, 5, in);

        for(i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            fscanf(in," %s %s ", temp[i].firstName, temp[i].lastName);
        fscanf(in,"%d %d %d %d %d %d ", &temp[i].numbers[0], 
&temp[i].numbers[1], &temp[i].numbers[2], &temp[i].numbers[3], 
&temp[i].numbers[4], &temp[i].numbers[5]);
    }
  }
else
{
printf("File is Not Exist.\n");
}
return temp;
}
```

I essentially need to only store the first and last name of the users that got 3 4 5 6 of the winning numbers correct.

Comment: Why are you opening the file multiple times?

Comment: Oops, I didn't mean to do that. Ill change that

Comment: BTW: your `getnum()` function is pointless. It reads six numbers and stores them in a _local_ array. Local variables go away once the function returns.

Comment: I know that I am doing it to skip the first line of the input file because the first line just tells me how many entries are in the file.

Answer (score 0):

I will admit that you only need hints to go past a problem.

Unrelated, but you never test your input functions. Beware a single incorrect line will give undefined results and you will not even know where the problem is. Remember: never trust what comes from the outside.

Back to your problem. A simple way is to use 2 nested loops, one on the winning numbers and one on the guessed ones just counting the matches: if the total number of matches is at least 3, you keep the record, else you reject it. You can even do that when reading the file (here in pseudo-code):

```
int recnum = 0;   // next record to store
for (int i=0; i<size; i++) {     // loop over the input file
    read the line into temp[recnum]
    int count = 0;                // number of correct guesses
    for (int j=0; j<6; j++) {     // loop over the winning numbers
        for (int k=0; k<6; k++) { // loop over the guessed numbers
            if winning[j] == guessed[k] {
                count++;
            }
        }
    }
    if (count >= 3) recnum++;      // only keep if at least 3 correct guesses
}
```